# access ID/GUID Attribute isPermaLink

Tags: php, rss, simplepie, xml-attribute

I use SimplePie to parse RSS feeds in php. For pre-processing the result of SimplePie, I need to know if the the link is a permalink or not. The info is stored in this XML element:

`<guid isPermaLink="false">FileNr123</guid>`

If `$items` is an instance of SimplePie objet that stands for one RSS feed item, I can use `$item->get_permalink` to get the permalink. Unfortunately this returns the fileName/guid, even if `isPermaLink="false"`

So how can I access the `isPermaLink` attribute of every feed item to post-process the SimplePie output?

Comment: Be careful though... There are cases when the isPermaLink is set to true, but the link is not a link :/ Our experience at [Superfeedr](https://superfeedr.com) is that you should always check the type and validity of the data in a feed!

Comment: Have you tried [get_item_tags()](http://simplepie.org/wiki/reference/simplepie_item/get_item_tags)?

Comment: @revent Yes, I did. Found this some days before. (see my answer) The problem is, that some Feeds mar that link as ` isPermaLink="false"`, even if the link is an valid link. So this is of cause not an simplepie Problem. its more a issue, how does the provider create the rss feed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On option is to use the `get_item_tags` method in order to walk trough the array and search for the first `isPermaLink`:

```
$guid = $item->get_item_tags('','guid');
$arrIt = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveArrayIterator($guid[0]));
foreach ($arrIt as $sub) {
   $subArray = $arrIt->getSubIterator();
   if (isset($subArray['isPermaLink']) && $subArray['isPermaLink'] == "false") 
       {$isPermalink = false ;break;}
}
```

This works, but it's not satisfying, bacause some RSS provider sets `isPermaLink` to `false` even the link works correctly for a long time.